# How to fix my designed calculator circuit using Logisim

Tags: digital-logic, diagram

I am trying to design a calculator circuit that adds 2 four-bit 2's-complement binary numbers as its input and outputs an 8-bit 2's-complement number when the control bits equal 01.

Here's what I have done so far using a software called Logisim. I am really stuck when I found out that I cannot put the other 4 output buttons (colored in blue) in my full adder. I am stumped on how to approach this problem now.

I have tested a few 2's-complement numbers and got the output I wanted and some 2's-complement numbers that did not go so well like (having 0100 as the first input and 0110 as the second input did not give me 1010 but gave me 1011.

[image: block diagram]

I just need help, suggestions and guidance on how to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 4-bit full adder, so far OK. Then you connected a control input to the carry-in of the lowest bit. When you keep that control at 0 you still have your 4-bit adder. When you put it at 1 you will get the addition + 1, just as you described. Putting an inverter after the first output bit will 'solve' this ONLY for additions that had a 0 in the lowest bit (go figure out why).

If you want the control = 1 to give you the addition, and control = 0 must give 'something else, does not matter what' you could put the inverter in the control line.

BTW a 4-bit added will give you a 5-bit result. If you need an 8-bit 2s-complement result look up 'sign extension'. (This smells of homework, so I won't give away everything.)

Comment: Hi Wouter! I know what sign extension is, I will need to pad the number in the front with 0's if its a positive number or 1's in the front if its a negative number. Based on your feedback, it seems like I'm on the right track but I'm just missing sign extension. However the addition implementation only works for several 4 bit's 2 complement number(because the inverter flips the bit) the only reason I added the inverter was I was getting unexpected results otherwise. How would I implement something like sign extension? I'm guessing I would probably have to wire the remaining output in some way.

Comment: Show me the inputs that don't work correctly with a carry-in of 0.

Comment: Hi Wouter, here's the link with the input that does not work. My circuit is suppose to perform addition(A + B) when first control bit is 0 and the second control bit is 1. However this input seems make my circuit work awkwardly. http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d86/warnexus/gatepic.png

Comment: You add 0b0100 + 0b0100 + 0b0001, you get 0b1011. Nothing wrong! The 0b0001 is beacuse the lower bit of what you call control is a 1 and you feed it into the carry-in of your lowest-bit adder.

Comment: but when you add 0100 + 0110, the output is 1010. My answer has to be wrong. I do not understand what did you mean about the 0B0100, that is not in my picture.

Comment: In the picture the leftmost input of the rightmost adder is connected to a 1. Hence you add an extra 0x0001.

Comment: I updated the circuit. the calculation works now but I cannot figure out the sign extension. http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d86/warnexus/aplusbnosignext.png